# Simple Web Crawler in Java - Multi-threaded yet slow :)

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler

I've searched but couldn't find the answer - it is not "code-wise" but more performance wise. If you remember an answer for my question though, I would be happy to be pointed there :)

I used a pretty simple architecture - There i a main thread containing a list of URLs "to be crawled" and a list of URLs crawled (with their HTML). Both structures are concurrent.
I create an initial thread for each of the 5 or 6 beginning sites, then:

1. Each thread adds itself to a list of "currently active threads" in the main thread. No threads will be added after we reach a certain maximum (I could use Executors, but chose not to for the moment, sorry for the inconvenience :) ).
2. It then downloads the HTML from the given URL, extracting all the links via Jsoup.
3. It if those URLs are not in the list of URLs "to be crawled", it adds them there.
4. When this process is done and the thread is about to exit from start(), it removes itself from the list of currently active threads.

The main thread just loops around all the time: if the list of URLs "to be crawled" isn't empty, and we haven't reached the maximal number of threads (again - sorry for lack of executors and the busy-wait...), create a new thread which traverses the next URL from the list etc.

The problem is - this process works, but **too slowly**. My connection speed is roughly 5Mbits (tested). The sites are crawled at a rate of about 1 per second (slowwww....). I printed the size of the html downloaded (simply via doc.html().size()) and calculated by myself, over a period of 25 seconds, that I use about 71Kbs. So obviously I'm doing something wrong even with this simple design and your input would be much appreciated.

Note1 - I am aware of crawler politeness and robots.txt. I will use those just as soon as I understand why I'm crawling so slowly.
Note2 - Really, I'm aware of the not so great design :) But it shouldn't account for the crawling speed as far as I can understand.

Thanks for reading!

```
public class Crawler {
public static final int MAX = 500;
public static final int MAX_THREADS = 100;

public static final String[] initialUrls = {"http://www.bbc.com",
                                            "http://www.facebook.com",
                                            "http://www.apple.com",
                                            "http://www.twitter.com",
                                            "http://www.tumblr.com",
                                            "http://www.microsoft.com"};

public static Vector<String> urls;
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String,Vector<String>> db;
public static Vector<Thread> threads;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    db = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Vector<String>>();
    urls = new Vector<String>();
    threads = new Vector<Thread>();

    for(int i = 0; i < initialUrls.length; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Parser(db, urls, initialUrls[i]);
        threads.add(t);
        t.start();
    }

    String address;
    while(db.size() < MAX)
    {
        if((urls.size() != 0) && (threads.size() < MAX_THREADS))
        {
            address = urls.get(0);
            urls.remove(0);
            Thread t = new Parser(db, urls, address);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    try
    {
        for(Thread t : threads)
        {
            t.join();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    // do something
}
```

}

```
public class Parser extends Thread{ 
public Vector<String> urls;
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Vector<String>> db;
public String start;

public Parser(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Vector<String>> db, Vector<String> urls, String start)
{
    this.db = db;
    this.start = start;
    this.urls = urls;
}

public void start()
{
    Crawler.threads.add(this);
    parsePage(start);
    Crawler.threads.remove(this);
}

private void parsePage(String page)
{
    if(db.size() >= Crawler.MAX)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(page).get();
        doc = Jsoup.parse(doc.toString());

        Vector<String> pageText = doc.html();

        if(db.size() < Crawler.MAX)
        {
            db.put(page, pageText);
        }

        String newPage;
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for(int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++)
        {
            newPage = links.get(i).attr("abs:href");
            if(!db.containsKey(newPage) && !urls.contains(newPage))
            {
                urls.add(newPage);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you used a profiler?

Comment: Why `Vector` in 2014? Also, have you considered using an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: If you have not done any profiling and determined it's _your_ code that's the problem ***and not the remote sites and internet connections***, then this is completely off-topic for SO.

Comment: Just lower `MAX_THREADS` value, I bet it will run much faster. Another thing is that you should use `ExecutorService` as @fge says. You should also consider that sending "a lot" of requests to one page in a short time can be recognized as DoS attack and in consequence blocked by remote host.

Comment: Hi all thanks for your input. In response to your questions -

Comment: @SargeBorsch I have not used a profiler but this is a good advice. I'm not that experienced with coding this kind of project so bare my ignorance: what profiler is preferable in this case? or does it not matter much?

Comment: @fge why not use Vector? It's pretty standard and thread-safe as far as I know. Do you recommend otherwise? As far as the ExecutorService - yes, I have thought of using those, but preferred to stick with what I know for starters.

Comment: @Jim I'm not sure what you said: I'm pretty sure its the code since the connection is OK but I thought maybe I'm making a huge mistake.

Comment: @Marciej I accidently put a wrong MAX_THREADS value, it should be 15 :) as for the hitting too many times on a single host - yes I have thought of that. But right now it is working very slowly. I thought I'd try and reach a better pace with a *basic* code, then immediately stop it and adhere to politeness issues when improving it :)

Comment: @user3381028 Any profiler would suffice, I think. Try the one that's bundled with Java first...

Comment: It is most likely NOT the code.  There are too many moving parts here and until you actually KNOW the code is the culprit you're just guessing.  Try watching the internet traffic with Wireshark to see where the delays are.

Comment: OK I'll try and profile my code then, never did that before :) (because I never had any error in the past... naturally...). @JimGarrison the statement that the code is *likely* not the problem is really helpful. I will do as you suggested. Thank you both and everyone else of course :)

Comment: @amirkr `Vector` was standard and thread safe 15 years ago; now it's obsolete. And you should really learn about `ExecutorService`, it has been part of the Java API for 10 years if not more and is waay easier to use than a bunch of `Thread`s.

Comment: @fge OK then the next thing I do after I determine the cause for the slow pace of the crawler is to switch to ExecutorService. What would you recommend instead of Vector? I have been using this structure quite a lot. ArrayList would be a logical alternative but it is not thread safe from what I read.

Comment: See my answer; you have no need for a thread-safe collection in your case if you use an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ExecutorService` and a `Map<String, Future<X>>`.

First: create an `ExecutorService`:

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(...);
```

Second: create a method which will return a `Callable<X>` where `X` is what you want returned:

```
private Callable<X> callableForURL(final String url)
{
    // implementation here
}
```

Third: take your list of URLs, submit your jobs to them:

```
for (final String url: initialUrls)
    map.put(url, executor.submit(callableForURL(url)));
```

Fourth: walk your `Map` and call `.get()` on each value to get the result.

Have a look at the javadoc for `ExecutorService` and `Executors`.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try that! Had only worked with ExecutorService and Future object a long time ago so this really saves me a lot of time figuring out the logic :)